# Can I implement OCaml modules with `let` or do I need to create a file for it?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

my_module.mli:

```
module Make
    (Something: SomeModule.S) = sig
    val f: t->t
    (*...*)
end
```

my_module.ml:

```
module Make
    (Something: SomeModule.S) = struct
    let f t = t
    (*...*)
end
```

Ok. Suppose that I want to instantiate my_module by doing `My_module.Make()`. I must pass a `Something: SomeModule.S`.

One way I found is by doing this:

something.mli

```
include SomeModule.S

val some_module_fn_1: t->t
```

something.ml

```
let some_module_fn_1 t = t
```

Now I think I can create a new file:

main.ml

```
let myModuleImpl = MyModule.Make(Something)

myModuleImpl.f 0
```

**But do I really need to create the separate files `something.mli` and `something.ml`?** Can't I simply create their implementations in `main.ml`?

Comment: Of course you can. Are you not reading the Cornell book anymore? Nowhere in [the section on functors](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2019sp/textbook/modules/using_functors.html) does it use `include`. It's typically `module MyModuleImpl = MyModule.Make(Something)`.

Comment: It's even possible to instantiate a functor inside a function using a local module binding: `let module MyModuleImpl = MyModule.Make(Something) in ...`

Comment: @glennsl so but wait, if I'm not implementing my `Something` in the `something.ml`, then how can I implement it? That was the main question: how to implement `A` to put into `MyModule.Make(A)`

Comment: Oh, that's just an ordinary submodule: `module Something = struct ... end`. From what I can see this is mostly what the book uses. I can't see it using files outside of the section on [Compilation Units](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2019sp/textbook/modules/compilation_units.html), which also describes the relationship between files and submodules. Not sure where you get the idea that you have to use files.